# Some streaming SoundCloud songs fail to stream on iOS with errors

Tags: ios, soundcloud, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to stream SoundCloud songs in my app, but some of them don't work, despite the streamable flag being true. An example of a song that doesn't work is "Black Friday" by Kendrick Lamar, with streaming URL

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/234989572/stream?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}
```

(with {MY_CLIENT_ID} being the actual ID, of course)

This is the error returned by the AVPlayerItem (again with the real client ID obscured):

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." 
UserInfo=0x7fe735752340 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe735751e30 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12938.)",
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/234989572/stream?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID},
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/234989572/stream?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID},
NSURL=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/234989572/stream?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID},
NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.}
```

Most songs play just fine, for example "Everything Will Be OK" by G-Eazy. URL:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/236005149/stream?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}
```

Why are some songs, like Black Friday, failing?

Answer (score 0):

The publisher of that track has opted not to provide an mp3 stream for it. Unfortunately, for some very complicated reasons, there's no way to tell that is going to be the case until you actually try to fetch the stream. It's a very frustrating thing, but please believe me when I say the reasons are complicated.

Perhaps sending a HEAD request to the streams endpoint before attempting to play would help?

Comment: I don't buy this answer.  Using the `trending-tracks` endpoint on`api-mobileweb.soundcloud.com`, I'm getting an `http_mp3_128_url` value returned.  There has to be an mp3 exposed for the web player and mobile app, but I assume it's all private.

Comment: Using the api-* domains apart from api.soundcloud.com aren't really recommended. They're used by the internal SC apps, so they won't be publicly documented, and there's no guarantee they'll continue to behave the same (or even exist) in the future.